# Not able to boot Windows after Ubuntu installation

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

After I installed Ubuntu with EFI file system, my device shows "No bootable device" and I can't boot windows 10, although I can boot ubuntu by going in boot manager. I also updated grub, but it still shows the same message of "No bootable device" on restarting and I can't boot Windows from boot manager too.

Comment: Grub can only boot working Windows. Very likely your Windows wasn't booting before if it doesn't boot now when directly selecting the Windows bootloader in UEFI settings.

Comment: So what should I try now?

Comment: You should ignore the wrong answer you got below, boot Windows installation media and try to perform a repair. Even if unsuccessful you can always reinstall Windows. In UEFI mode it can be done for any OS part of dual or multi boot system, unlike what the answer suggests/advices. Repairing or reinstalling Windows will probably change the boot order to the Windows bootloader manager, just change it back to Ubuntu (Grub) **after assuring Windows is booting correctly**, the boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. Now Windows should boot correctly from Grub as well. Maybe this is an actual answer?

Comment: So the solution that I understood is reinstalling windows, right?                                            Further If I reinstall windows, will the data be still stored that was there before in hard drive?

Comment: No, the first thing to try is repair, there's a special environment you can use when booting the Windows media.

Comment: But how can I repair windows when I'm not able to boot it. Can u tell something about that "special environment"?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro

Comment: Are you booting in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode and Windows is UEFI? Check UEFI settings & see if Windows then directly boots from UEFI boot menu. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/